# cant connect to remote redis server from java spring application

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, lettuce

I'm working on java spring app.
I'm trying to use @Cachable annotation with customized cache configuration.
its working as expected when connecting to redis on my machine (localhost),
but when I change address and username and password to my remote redis server,
I get "Read time out" exception on HealthCheck.
**my remote server is using TLS**, I guess this is what causing this exception but I didnt find how to enable this.
I used lettuce (6.0.4.RELEASE) and used RedisStandaloneConfiguration (spring-data-redis 2.4.7).

can someone please help me with this issue ?

this is my error log:

```
2022-11-03 18:53:14 [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] WARN  o.s.b.a.redis.RedisHealthIndicator - Redis health check failed
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.fetchConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:193)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:105)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.redis.RedisHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RedisHealthIndicator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:59)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:288)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:15)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:273)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:43)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:155)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:220)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:278)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:196)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.auth(BinaryJedis.java:2284)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:899)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:429)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:354)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:126)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Comment: *java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out* You are sure your configuration is correct and there are no proxies and firewalls which blocks you?

Comment: Yes! Very sure. In the same app Im using jedis that is able to connect to this server. But when I try to connect to this server with this customization I get this error about healthCheck.